# To reshape a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

The shape of SegAllFeat is (850,80) & that ogListOfFrame2Vec is (0,118,80). Both SegAllFeat and ListofFrame2Vec are NumPy arrays.

```
def function_FeatureExtract(path, indices, featureNum, classLabel):

    extension = '.wav'

    ListOfFrame2Vec = np.empty((0, frame_number, featureNum))
    LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec = np.empty((0, 1, 1))

    DictionaryFiletoIndex=[]

    for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in files_list:
            #if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
            audiofile = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            print(audiofile)
            audio, s_rate = librosa.load(audiofile, sr=sample_rate)
            #print(file_name)
            segment_start_flag=0
            start_seg = 0
            while (start_seg + segment_length) < len(audio):

                sound1 = audio[start_seg:(start_seg + segment_length)]

                featureSet=function_FeatureExtractfromSinglewindow(sound1, hop_length, sample_rate)

                if segment_start_flag==0:
                    SegAllFeat=featureSet
                    segment_start_flag=1
                else:
                    SegAllFeat=np.vstack((SegAllFeat,featureSet))

                start_seg = start_seg + overlappiong

            if segment_start_flag==1:
                SegAllFeat=normalize(SegAllFeat, norm = 'l2', axis=0)
                SegAllFeat=SegAllFeat[:, indices[0:featureNum]]

            ListOfFrame2Vec = np.append(ListOfFrame2Vec, array([SegAllFeat]), axis=0)

            if classLabel == 1:
                LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec=np.append(LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec,np.array([1]))
            else:
                LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec = np.append(LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec, np.array([0]))
            #LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec



            DictionaryFiletoIndex.append(file_name)


            print(ListOfFrame2Vec.shape)
            print(LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec.shape)
    return ListOfFrame2Vec, LabelOfTotalFrame2Vec, DictionaryFiletoIndex
```

I need to reshape SegAllFeat to (0,850,80). What should I do to get this shape?

Comment: What's the purpose of creating an array with 0 elements?  You can create an array with that shape, but you can't reshape an array to it (unless it too has 0 elements).  I'm not sure you understand what it means to have a shape like (0,850,80), or why it might be useful.

Comment: Doing `vstack` and `np.append` in a loop is inefficient.  Both use `np.concatenate`, and make a new array each time - with a increasing amount of copying.  It's better to collect arrays in a list (list append is pretty efficient), and do just one `concatenate` at the end.  And that way you don't need to create this odd 0-element start array.

Comment: When I made the first comment I should have realized that you were doing repeated concatenates.  That's about the only reason for making an array with shape (0,...).

Comment: While working on a ML project, we encountered the following value error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 118 and the array at index 1 has size 850.

Comment: The line of code causing the error is:

ListOfFrame2Vec = np.append(ListOfFrame2Vec, array([SegAllFeat]), axis=0)